# A lot of answers remain unselected

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, unaccepted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A good answer exists but is not accepted](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/460/a-good-answer-exists-but-is-not-accepted)

A lot of questions in game dev have answers but they are not selected as an answer of the question. Can the situation be improved in anyway?

Comment: Only if the people select answers for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accepting an answer isn't required; the community voting moves the "best" answers to the top naturally.

Accept is more of a social convention and a "hey, thanks man, this really helped me!" connection between the asker and answerer, than anything else.

Comment: So, 'not selecting answer' is not a problem, even if it is suitable?

Comment: @iamcreasy: No, it's not a "problem," per se. It's considered "good manners" to reciprocate someone's hard work, so we provided that feature. A lot of folks feel slighted when the original author fails to close that loop and offer that bit of gratitude -- so we built in an 'accept rate' to remind them: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/

Comment: Hey why haven't you accepted this answer @iamcreasy :)

Comment: @tim-holt well there were some JS error with my browser on the time I tried to accept it. Nothing was working. Now, its back again.